# Django order_by causes query to be very slow

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model `Line` with a `total_value` and a `group` fields.
I use the following code to get the 10 lines with the highest values within a given group:

```
group_lines = Line.objects.filter(group_id=group_pk, total_value__gt=0)
sorted_lines = group_lines.order_by('-total_value')[:10]
ids = lines.values_list("id", flat=True)
```

My database is very large, with 10M+ lines. The `group_lines` query alone returns 1000 lines.

My issue is that the `values_list` query takes about 2 seconds to get executed.
If I remove the ordering, it is almost instant.

Is it normal to take that long to order 1000 objects? How can I make this query faster?

I am on Django 2.1.7, with a MySQL database.

Comment: Please provide the relevant model.

Comment: Try adding  an index on the total_value field

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem what do you want to see? It's a model with various integer, textfield and foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an index on the database field. This will, for most database, use a B-tree, which will boost sorting significantly:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    # …
    total_value = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

you can also use a combined index:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    # …
    total_value = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['group', 'total_value'])
        ]
```

This will both boost filtering and ordering the values.

Updating an index will have time complexity *~O(* log *N)* which is comparable to filtering, etc. and retrieving will often happen in *~O(* log *N)* as well.

Comment: Can I use total_value as an index even if it  is not unique?

Comment: @RyanPergent: yes, then it will create a MUL index.

Comment: That did it, the ordering is instant now :)